# Bootstrap centered logo navigation issue in responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I have been playing with Bootstrap for sometime and wanted to use a centered logo.
However with the use of some media queries and CSS I managed to make the logo centered in a bigger display. I also added several media queries to adjust the logo and the navigation for different width sizes. However when the size goes lower from 768px (for example 767px). The logo and navigation is kind of messed up. I just want to have a drop down below the logo. 
You can see the live version with pure HTML based on bootstrap here:

http://info.sunnyindustries.net/Work/FHS/

I tried several things but I was not able to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a min-width property to your div so that at some point the page will stop trying to resize and the viewer will just get a scroll bar. This site does this for instance.

Comment: No, i want it to be responsive. I want that button to appear and a navigation drop down when the size goes below 767px.